# MusicBrainz alternative for JavaEE

Tags: java, open-source, jakarta-ee, musicbrainz

Is there any Java/J2EE website which opensource their software and data 
(like musicbrainz.org, where a developer can easily set up a personal/development MusicBrainz website by downloading the Perl/CGI webapp and the music data in PostgreSQL dump) ?

It would be good for other developers to learn from this kind of website.

Thanks

Comment: If you are looking to modify existing source code, would it not be simple to take any large demo app shipped with app-servers like glassfish and re-use it? I am not sure I get the full extent of what you are looking for. A Java/J2EE app may be built for any domain, so I am not sure if you are looking for some specific domain or just just some project which illustrates most components  of J2EE.

Comment: I am looking for opensource Java/J2EE app that has been running in production and also gives others the data, pretty much like MusicBrainz or Slashcode (but built on Java).

Answer (score 1):

MusicBrainz [expose a set of web services](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/XMLWebService) so you could use these to create your own J2EE application. I know this isn't exactly what you are looking for but in a lot of respects it is better, the amount of data MusicBrainz would have to store and query would be huge and require (several) large server(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can consider CRMs like [eXo platform](http://www.exoplatform.com/portal/public/website/) or [XWiki](http://www.xwiki.com/xwiki/bin/view/Home/WebHome), which are mass deployed

Comment: both of them don't offer the data (like the music/artist data from musicbrainz). I suppose it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mbslave](https://github.com/lalinsky/mbslave) to get a database containing the musicbrainz database.

Then [search-server](https://bitbucket.org/metabrainz/search-server) is a pure-java application that provides the search part of the musicbrainz webservice. You could extend this to provide additional functionality required.